# Training in HR Zone 5

Tags: heart-rate-monitor, heart

I am sure this question has done the rounds, so pardon me if I regurgitate an old topic, but today I did my usual cycling time trial (steep hill), and broke my PB. I then checked my HR stats and my average was 172, maximum 186 but the time I spent training in Zone 5 was 14 minutes (of a 21:48 course) ***

I am 43 and male, I would say I was pretty fit but hardly Chris Froome. I push myself on this ride to almost my limit (I stress, almost) and although I don't have much left in the tank, I would also refute any claim that I am at my absolute limit and ready to pass out or puke. Put simply, I can cope with this level of intensity.

Either I am very fit, which I doubt, given the time to distance ratio (see my stats) or very unfit and need to rethink my training. You can also see my HR recovery although I did not just stop... there were Russians drinking vodka in the forest at the top of the route and I didn't want inviting to join them (a refusal may offend), so I stopped and walked away with the bike slowly but purposefully :D

I am mindful that we are advised not to train like this but my body does basically allow it (although as I said it is not exactly easy).

Does anybody have any thoughts?

*** NB I started the stopwatch late, I use Runtastic to time myself, Garmin just for HR and I forgot to start it, and then forgot to stop it at the finish line, hence the time discrepancy.

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts about what.......?

Answer (score 1):

I would say : Listen to your body and track your progression rather than blindly following prescription such as "don't train too much in zone 5"

First, you may not actually be in your zone 5. Your monitor could not be 100% accurate. Did you perform an actual lab test to determine your zones ?

Second, if your body and mind both recover well from such training sessions (i.e. you sleep well, you feel good, you do not feel completely broken physically and mentally, you still want to train) and your metrics of interest (speed, endurance, ...) keep improving, then all good.

Each person is different and responds differently to a training stimulus. If this works for you, all fine. Although remember also to think long term. If at some point you start noticing little injuries, pain, ... This might also be an indication that you are training too hard without enough rest.